# SQL server query to search and stuff multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, string-aggregation, stuff

I have table **employee_table** which is like this

```
org     employeeid (int)    firstname   lastname
1234    56788934            Suresh      Raina
1234    56793904            Virat       Kohli
```

then i have **project_table** which is like this

```
Project     members (varchar)
A123        56788934,56793900
```

Now i need to fetch corresponding names of employees and stuff in a single row like this.

```
Project     members (varchar)
A123        Suresh Raina, Virat Kohli
```

I have written below query which is not working. please help.

```
SELECT project,
   (
            SELECT   message_text = Stuff(
                     (
                            SELECT ', ' + Concat(firstname,' ',lastname)
                            FROM   employee_table t1
                            WHERE  t1.org = t2.org
                            AND    CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.userid) IN (Concat('''',Replace(pt.members,',',''','''),'''')) --adding single quotes at start and end of each number
                                   FOR xml path ('')) , 1, 1, '')
            FROM     employee_table t2
            WHERE    t2.userid IN
            group BY org;) FROM project_table pt
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Why is it not working?  Does it error out?  Does it give incorrect results?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Fix your design, don't store delimited data in your database. Fix that, and your problem disappears.

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.userid)` **Always** specify the length of your (n)varchar's

Comment: Sorry i did not mention the version. My sql version is 2014. I am getting no records as output from my query mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for SQL Server 2017 onwards.

It is using a pair of handy functions available in SQL Server 2017:

- `STRING_SPLIT()`
- `STRING_AGG()`

Method #2 covers solution for SQL Server 2008 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @employee TABLE (org INT, employeeid INT, firstname VARCHAR(20), lastname VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @employee (org, employeeid, firstname, lastname) VALUES
(1234, 56788934, 'Suresh', 'Raina'),
(1234, 56793904, 'Virat', 'Kohli');

DECLARE @project TABLE (project CHAR(4), members VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @project (project, members) VALUES
('A123', '56788934,56793904');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- Method #1, SQL Server 2017 onwards
SELECT p.project, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(e.firstname, SPACE(1), e.lastname), ', ') AS members
FROM @project AS p CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(members, ',') AS s
    INNER JOIN @employee AS e ON s.value = e.employeeid
GROUP BY p.project;

-- Method #2, SQL Server 2008 onwards
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
      , TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
         REPLACE(members, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @project
), cte AS 
(
    SELECT project
        , e.*
    FROM rs CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root/r/text()') AS t(c)
        INNER JOIN @employee AS e ON c.value('.','INT') = e.employeeid
)
SELECT project
    , STUFF((SELECT @separator + CAST(CONCAT(o.firstname, SPACE(1), o.lastname) AS VARCHAR(30)) AS [text()]
         FROM cte AS O
         WHERE O.project = C.project 
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS Members
FROM cte AS c
GROUP BY project;
```

**Output**

```
+---------+---------------------------+
| project |          members          |
+---------+---------------------------+
| A123    | Suresh Raina, Virat Kohli |
+---------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Sorry i did not mention the version. My sql version is 2014. I am getting no records as output from my query mentioned in the question. can you suggest me a solution for sql 2014?

Comment: @curiousboy, I updated the answer with Method #2. Check it out.